# Transferring files with SFTP

Tags: file, ssh, sftp, transfer

So I'm trying to transfer files to a remote computer on an SSH system. 'I've used the `sftp` command, used `lls` to confirm the presence of the file in the local computer, and then implemented the `put filename` command. However, I receive the same result each time:

```
stat filename: No such file or directory
```

I just don't know what's going wrong! Any help or troubleshooting tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? Usually, in a *UX system, `scp` will do the job.

Comment: I'm sorry if the description is inadequate, I'm quite new to all this. I was instructed to use `sftp`- when I try `scp` it yields something about inauthenticity of the host.

Comment: Show us your complete code as well as a complete output from `sftp`, Use "edit" link below the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're currently using Windows you can download [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) and use that to transfer files. It has a nice graphic interface that is easy to interact with

Answer (score 0):

Well, supposing that you are on a Linux/Unix environment, you could use `scp`. Typically, the syntax for an scp command would be like this:

```
$ scp foobar.txt your_username@remotehost.net:/some/remote/directory
```

The above command copies the file `foobar.txt` which resides in the local computer, to a specific directory in the remote machine, using a username (you will be asked for a password later).

Comment: Alright, I run into issues with `scp` though- I don't have a password, only an SSH key passphrase. I typically avoid all the password requests with `ssh-agent`. Is there some way to access `scp` without a password?

Comment: Yes it's possible. I haven't done this but there is a ton of examples and tutorials in the wild. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/06/perform-ssh-and-scp-without-entering-password-on-openssh/

Comment: Right, from what I've found all of those resources tackle making SSH password free. I've done that, there's just some kink that prevents SCP from being similarly accessible.

Comment: Okay, update: I've managed to navigate the password issue, but I still receive "No such file or directory" as a result.

Comment: I know that this is your first time, but take some time to read Stack Overflow's policy about questions and answers. Generally, this is not a help forum, but a place where you ask specific questions and expect specific answers. Most users here will ignore (or even worse, downvote) your questions, because they seem to lack personal effort, details, or both (i.e. I still don't know what OS you're using, so, technically, my answer is wrong). Being a new user myself, I'm just telling this to you as an advice.

Comment: According to your issue, usually, this message is due to wrong paths used in the command. Double check that the paths you're using are valid for BOTH machines, and if you want to be 100% sure, use absolute paths.

If your file named `foobar.txt` resides on `/home/bob/test` use `/home/bob/test/foobar.txt` as a source path.

Answer (score 0):

The `sftp` command line client uses the ssh transport and will tunnel your connections using your key. So if you have ssh access, you should also have sftp access. This is a secure option for people who are more comfortable with ftp. Most GUI ftp clients should also support sftp.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing also in this issue when trying to upload files from the local to the remote server. I did commands well and clean but the mistake I was making was that: I've logged into the remote server with `ssh` ***and then*** login with `sftp`. In that way, `sftp` will consider that your remote server is the local (as I logged in first to this via `ssh`) when using the command below:

```
put /c/path/to/file.txt
```

So, the thing to do is to login directly to the server via `sftp` and putting your local files in there.